# Hadoop MapReduce error while parsing CSV

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm getting following error in map function while parsing a CSV file.

```
14/07/15 19:40:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1403602091361_0018_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
        at com.test.mapreduce.RetailCustomerAnalysis_2$MapClass.map(RetailCustomerAnalysis_2.java:55)
        at com.test.mapreduce.RetailCustomerAnalysis_2$MapClass.map(RetailCustomerAnalysis_2.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
```

The map function is given below

```
package com.test.mapreduce;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;



public class RetailCustomerAnalysis_2 extends Configured implements Tool {
     public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase
     implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

          private Text key1 = new Text();
          private Text value1 = new Text();



     public void map(Text key, Text value,
                     OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
                     Reporter reporter) throws IOException {


         String line = value.toString();
         String[] split = line.split(",");


         key1.set(split[0].trim()); 
         /* line no 55 where error is occuring */
         value1.set(split[4].trim()); 


         output.collect(key1, value1);
     }
 }


 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Configuration conf = getConf();

     JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, RetailCustomerAnalysis_2.class);

     Path in = new Path(args[0]);
     Path out = new Path(args[1]);
     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

     job.setJobName("RetailCustomerAnalysis_2");
     job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
     job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

     job.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
     job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
     job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    // job.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");

     JobClient.runJob(job);

     return 0;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
     int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new RetailCustomerAnalysis_2(), args);

     System.exit(res);
 }

}
```

Sample Input used to run this code is as follows

```
PRAVEEN,4002012,Kids,02GK,7/4/2010
PRAVEEN,400201,TOY,020383,14/04/2014
```

I'm running the application using the following command and Inputs.

```
yarn jar RetailCustomerAnalysis_2.jar com.test.mapreduce.RetailCustomerAnalysis_2 /hduser/input5 /hduser/output5
```

Comment: Make sure you check if the value passed to the mapper is null or whitespace. I wouldn't be surprised if you were being passed an extra empty line.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I have checked the file using vi there are no whitespaces or empty line.

Comment: That's fine but I would put it in the code anyway.  You don't control what happens before the data gets to your mapper so its usually best to assume the worst.

Comment: Can you please specify where and what changes have to be made in the code, thanks in advance, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I can't as Im on my phone.  Just check if the `Text value` is null or whitespace.

Comment: Modified the following line to remove whitespaces in map function : -     String line = value.toString().replaceAll("\\s+","");                       Still facing the same problem :(

Comment: Don't remove it.  Think about it.  If the line is empty and you split on a `,`, is there going to be anything at index 4?  You need to return if its empty.

Comment: Hi please help me with the modified code , whenever you can , I'll really appretiate it. Thx

Comment: I added the following line to deal with empty lines                             **if(value.toString().trim().isEmpty())                             {
 System.out.println("value is empty");
 }                                                                 else {Continue processing   }**                                 but still facing the same problem.

Comment: @Rahuul what is that `KeyValueTextInputFormat`? BTW please don't use the italic html tags, but the code tags. Your question was horrible to read.

Comment: Hi Thomas , thanks for the input, I used TextInputFormat instead of KeyValueTextInputFormat at job.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class); and it worked :) Sorry for the trouble you faced while reading my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Add check to see if input line has all fields defined or ignore processing it map function. Code would be something like this in new API.

```
    if(split.length!=noOfFields){
                        return;
        }
```

Additionally, if you are further interested you can set up hadoop countner to know how many rows were in total which dint contain all required fields in csv file.

```
    if(split.length!=noOfFields){
            context.getCounter(MTJOB.DISCARDED_ROWS_DUE_MISSING_FIELDS)
            .increment(1);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Hi rVr thanks for the answer , but I dont think it will help , as I tried running the code with only 2 lines of input values, which had all the fields. But Still I faced the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

split[] has elements split[0], split[1], split[2] and split[3] only

Answer (score 0):

In case of **KeyValueTextInputFormat** the first String before the separator is considered as the key and rest of the line is considered as value. A byte separator(coma OR whitespace etc.) is used to separate between key and value from every record.

In your code the first string before first coma is taken as the key and rest of line is taken as value. And as you split the value, there are only 4 strings in it. Therefore the String array can go from split[0] to split[3] only instead of split[4].

Any suggestions or corrections are welcomed.